# Selecting data that could reside in many databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

This is so complicated (in my head at least) that I couldn't title my question properly.

I have hundreds of databases (one for each `Supplier`) that I need to connect to from a central database that contains `Order`, `Customer`, and `Supplier` tables.

Basically the `Suppplier` table in the central database is like this:

```
SupplierID | SupplierName | SupplierDatabaseName
1            Nestle         Nestle005
2            Mars           Mars001
```

It holds details about a Supplier and most importantly what their Database Name is called.

When a customer places an Order it goes into the central database Order table like this:

```
OrderID | CustomerID | SuppplierID | ProductID | Qty
1         1            2             100         5
```

In the Supplier's database such as Mars001 there is a table for that company to manage information about their products like such:

```
ProductID | ProductName
100         Skittles
```

What I need to do is return a list of orders by a customer, along with the `ProductName`. This means I have to:

1. Select everything from the central database's `Order` table
2. Somehow dynamically provide the Supplier's database name to be used in a JOIN statement to get the ProductName out of the Products table in that database

The final output should look like this:

```
OrderID | CustomerID | SupplierID | ProductID | ProductName
1         1            2            100         Skittles
```

I understand dynamic sql to some extent, and I can dynamically supply a database name using a parameter. But that only works when the parameter value will stay the same in a query. This is more complex than that.

Could anyone please a suggest a way of tackling this? Perhaps its not possible to do in a single query?

Comment: This is a case of very vary bad database design. Say you have a product A supplied by 100 suppliers you need to create 100 connections from your application to each database and run a query against it. Are all your databases sitting on the same server ? If so you could write a stored procedure which can query all the databases but think about performance. Other option is to have some kind of schedule job which can sync data from all supplier databases to your central database and query your central database only .

Comment: its the combination of ProductID and SupplierID that makes it unique. So ProductID 100 could be a Fridge if its from SupplierID 32. Basically each Supplier has their own database in which to manage their products. But all orders are held centrally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this type of partitioning might not be the best, maybe you're stuck with it. The basic dynamic SQL to do what you want isn't that hard though:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) 
select @sql = N'
    select o.orderid, o.customerid, s.supplierid, p.productid, p.productname 
    from [order] o 
    join Supplier s on o.SuppplierID = s.SupplierID 
    join ' + s.Supplierdatabasename + N'..product p on o.ProductID = p.productid'
from [order] o join Supplier s on o.SuppplierID = s.SupplierID

exec(@sql)
```

This would get you a result like:

```
orderid     customerid  supplierid  productid   productname
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------
1           1           2           100         Skittles
```

The query can certainly be improved but it should give you an idea about how to proceed.

Comment: I do have the ability to change the db design if need be. however it seemed a good idea to do it this way because it meant each company could manage their products independently of each other

Comment: Well this worked splendidly. Just what I needed thank you jpw